# newbie, Installing app to samsung phone

Tags: android

I'm just getting started with android programming,
playing with HelloWorld and Eclipse.

I'd like to know how to install my apps to my samsung Galaxy S

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) to run your project on your device

**To sum up:**

First, from your phone (this is on HTC Desire anyway), go to Settings -> Applications -> Development and tick "USB debugging". (See the link above for device recognition problems)

Add `android:debuggable="true"` to your Manifest.xml in the `<application>` tag

From Eclipse, run your project then you will be asked to choose to run the project either to an AVD (the emulator) or the device.